# NoClassDefFoundError when init a SpringBoot 2 application in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jar

I have a SpringBoot 2 application, that when starts I got this error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/bonanza/BonanzaHelper;
```

I went to the service that uses this class:

```
public class BonanzaService {   
    @Autowired
    private BonanzaHelper bonanzaHelper;
```

I use Ctrl and click on the class and I got this message: `Cannot find declaration to go to`
but if I use `Shift + Ctrl + N` I can find the class in my maven repositoy

the class is imported in a `parent` group in the `pom.xml`

Comment: have you checked you dependencies (maven, gradle) or local libs that you require a module that contains that class? BonanzaHelper also looks like a custom class developed by you or your company?!

Comment: Can you post your directory structure? Ideally, everything must be in SpringApplication.class package or subpackage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may look like one of the following:
1. You may have two dependencies in the pom that point to a different version of the artifact with different locations

2. The class is not declared as Bean, so you can autowired it, you can do it in the @configuration file :

   @Bean
   public ObjectMapper bonanzaHelper() { return new BonanzaHelper();}